Why the core id is interleaved in range?
I have a NUMA system with two socket, I'm curious why the core id in NUMA0 is 0-15&32-47, instead of 0-31.
Additional information: Hyper thread disabled in BIOS;
Some related boot args: numa_balancing=disable.
Didn't use nosmt boot args.
Full output of lscpu:
 lscpu
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          46 bits physical, 57 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   64
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-63
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6458Q
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                143
    Thread(s) per core:   1
    Core(s) per socket:   32
    Socket(s):            2
    Stepping:             8
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   22%
    CPU max MHz:          4000.0000
    CPU min MHz:          800.0000
    BogoMIPS:             6200.00
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni
                          pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cat_l2 cdp_l3 cdp_l2 ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp
                           ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc
                          cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local split_lock_detect avx_vnni avx512_bf16 wbnoinvd dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_pkg_req hfi vnmi avx512vbmi umip pku ospke waitpkg avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg tme avx512_v
                          popcntdq la57 rdpid bus_lock_detect cldemote movdiri movdir64b enqcmd fsrm md_clear serialize tsxldtrk pconfig arch_lbr ibt amx_bf16 avx512_fp16 amx_tile amx_int8 flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:         VT-x
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                    3 MiB (64 instances)
  L1i:                    2 MiB (64 instances)
  L2:                     128 MiB (64 instances)
  L3:                     120 MiB (2 instances)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):           2
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0-15,32-47
  NUMA node1 CPU(s):      16-31,48-63


Linux does not make guarantees in how CPUs are numbered.
Various platform implementation details could change the numbering. Chiplet implementation on the die resulting in half reporting a bit differently.  CPUs going offline and online as a RAS or hardware licensing feature. Probably the former is more of a thing on this Xeon x86 than the latter, but that's a guess.
In practice, I would run a NUMA aware software distribution. And default to being hands off of the CPU scheduler.  This is a 32 core socket with NUMA. Linux knows that and will schedule related tasks on the same socket where possible. When a single shared data workload (database, virtual machine) exceeds 32 CPUs, check if the user software is NUMA aware and can be tuned for remote memory access.
Manually binding to specific CPUs (taskset affinity) is possible, but it is difficult to do better than the scheduler.  If you must meddle with specific CPUs, query for CPU numbers and group by node.   lscpu --parse   to get a list.

Great points, I need to bind cpu mannually to get less interrupts on that cpu. I will use lscpu --parse to achieve it.
